Piano practice : feeling stuck
I am an intermediate level classical piano student and have started taking jazz piano classes in parallel. I can spare up to 4 hours for music practice in my daily schedule. I have a trained ear for identifying melody ( I learnt Indian classical vocals for 6 years ).
The issue is I am unable to focus:

It’s usually one piece that takes up most of the practice time. Like recently I was given a sonatina by my classical teacher and I couldn’t devote adequate time to the jazz standard given by my jazz teacher.

∵ I am a singer, I try to accompany myself while singing. This is usually half an hour toward the end of practice session. However the accompaniment is very sloppy(I know the chords but I slip here and there). Besides if I pick up a transcription of the pop song(like I did for Tiny dancer recently) it becomes a new task altogether.
So I am never satisfied with the accompaniment as it doesn’t really sound like the typical one and I end up feeling totally lost after my practice.

To make things worse, I have been losing interest in practice. I do warmup play some random stuff and then give up.


What should I do? Do I focus only on one genre? Is there someway in which I can structure my routine and gain some sense of achievement at the end of each practice session, which motivates me to be consistent?

You might find some useful tips in Teaching unmotivated students.

What is your motivation for playing music? Do you do it for yourself or for someone else? Do you want to become a professional or do you just enjoy playing? Of the styles you mentioned which do you most enjoy playing?

I think you should revisit your goals. If you don’t know what your goals are, it’s almost impossible to make an informed choice about what to do next. It might be that losing sight of your goals is your only problem. In terms of this question, it’s hard to give any thoughts on how to get out of your situation without knowing where you’re trying to go. We need to know your goals as much as you do.

For starters, four hours practice time is way, way too much all in one go, which is what I suspect you try to do. It's rather like having just one meal a day, and making it a banquet!
Split things up into bite-sized (pun intended) bits, maybe even fifteen minutes before a break. A lot of learning goes on when one is not concentrating on the subject in hand, especially when one sleeps.
So, spend a lot less time on one particular part, then perhaps vary it with a completely different musical task. Playing classical and jazz simultaneously isn't the best idea - they're opposite ends of the musical spectrum. I might even play one one day, and leave the other until the next.
Most likely you haven't discussed this problem with either of your teachers, who may well be horrified by the thought of what you're attempting. They both want you to excel in their own genre, and will be of the opinion that there's little or no common ground. There again, they may come up with an amicable solution that suits you - and them.

Come on dver - be brave and explain your reason - if you can.

OMAD might be the healthiest way to eat. Not sure about banquet-sized portions though :)

(In case it baffled anyone else too, I suspect that OMAD = One Meal A Day.)

Practice routine for classical

Is there someway in which I can structure my routine and gain some sense of achievement at the end of each practice session, which motivates me to be consistent?

I think 4 hours a day at your level is too much.  When I was at the intermediate level doing classical piano, I only practiced an hour a day structured this way:

Scales and arpeggios for warm up: 5-10 minutes
Etudes: 10 minutes
Pieces: 3 at a time, from 3 different periods (Baroque, Classical, and Romantic), 40-45 minutes.  A sonatina would be part of the Classical period, but that's not the only repertoire I practice.

Tips:

My teacher wouldn't let me spend more than a few weeks on a piece; if it's good enough we move on to another piece.  That way I was never bored.  When you reach the advanced level, it makes sense to spend a few months on a piece.  For now, you're learning the building blocks for the technique and interpretation.
I also listened to recordings and try to emulate.  This motivates me to play better.  But it is unrealistic to try to play as good as a recording artist.  Even if you can play all the notes (such as Mozart's Sonata semplice, No. 16), that level of performance comes years later.
Every year I take ABRSM exam and played in front of an audience along with my teacher's other students, that gave me a sense of accomplishment.
Find a friend to play duets; there are 4 hands arrangements of classical pieces out there.  One piece I had a lot of fun with was playing Mozart's Eine Kleine Nachtmusik with my sister (sample performance here).

Non-Classical Genre

Do I focus only on one genre?

If you have additional 30 minutes, it should be perfectly fine to practice pop / jazz in addition to classical.
I also practiced pop songs in two different forms:

lead sheet (only melody, lyrics, and chords)
written out sheet music

The advantage of doing BOTH lead sheet + sheet music is that I try to emulate how to produce chord realizations and rhythms similar to how published sheet music does it, with my teacher as a guide.
Tips:

As you can get closer to realizing the chords & rhythms like how a sheet music does it, you will feel a sense of achievement.
Pick pieces from a variety of rhythmic styles: pop, swing, jazz, bossa nova / samba / rhumba, ballad, blues, etc.
Don't work on a piece for too long, though, that can be boring.
Listen to recordings too.
Find a friend to sing the pop songs with you playing the accompaniment.  Two people are more fun.  Better yet, find a drummer / bassist.


(IME, published sheet music for modern styles is often a lowest common denominator: uninspired, overly simplified, and not always good at capturing the groove or feel.  — Of course, in most cases a full backing track is pretty much impossible to reproduce from just one piano!  But with some experimentation and practice you can often do a better job than the sheet music.  It could make a good starting point, but I'd hope that as your ability and experience improve, you might aim higher.)

I agree that most published sheet music are too plain, but OP is intermediate.  Groove / feel can only be learned from listening.  More advanced pianist should learn from much more elaborate transcriptions / arrangements for solo piano. Examples of semi-advanced arrangements: Besame Mucho, Hey Jude, and Fly me to the moon.  Groove / feel can should lis

Good answer, but I disagree a bit about not spending more than few weeks on a piece (that's too difficult because you're always rushing forward). For me the greatest demotivator was going through endless list of pieces but never getting anything to stage where it would sound like music and not just barely hitting the right notes at right time.

@ojs What I said "if it's good enough we move on to another piece".  So what I mean is that the teacher wouldn't move on until I can at least play all the notes correctly and the piece sounds musical enough for my level.  I also didn't mention that sometimes he would spend more time on the piece if he saw I like it, especially when there are opportunities to use segments of the piece to illustrate pianistic techniques that can be applied elsewhere.  Secondly, my teacher also recommended me to revisit older pieces I like and practice them for recital; that's outside the 1-hour practice routine.
